# Computer switches itself off periodically, but works fine at a friend's house

Tags: windows-xp, power-supply

After running my computer for some time (anything between two minutes to two hours) it switches off and stays that way. When I try to start it again, my hard disk activity LED lights up, CPU and graphics card fans start to spin, the drives start rotating and all, but the system does not switch on.

It can be restarted only after some time (which again, varies between two minutes to 20 hours). I think my PC hates me. I haven't ever been able to operate it properly for more than two months continuously.

I also noticed that in the hardware monitor in BIOS, the +5V reading is showing in red (in place of blue) the voltage 0.124 or something in that range. This should be near 5V as far as I understand.

I've seen this problem reported by many users and tried out the solutions given to them:

- Switched my power supply - to no improvement
- Connected it directly to the wall socket - no effect
- Took it to a friend's house and tried. Voila it runs like a racehorse, no problems whatsoever. The BIOS readings are all in place!

So I'm guessing it's a problem with the electricity connection at home (In India that's definitely a possibility). But then how come my old computer performed without any problems for two years?

I'm going nuts over this as no service people here seem to know a solution. I can't even buy a new rig. What if the problem shows up in it too!

My configuration:

- Intel Dual Core 2.6GHz
- Asuz P5SD2-VM mother board
- 1GB Corsair RAM DDR2
- Sparkle 9400GT 1GB
- 500GB SATA + 40GB PATA
- CD & DVD drives
- 400W PSU (the culprit?)
- iBall UPS

Ok...guys i'm updating this.The motherboard was causing the trouble.Replaced it.Not a surprise because it had already broken down thrice.Servicing doesn't help,I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flaky electricity may have contributed to the problem, but what you're describing sounds like a faulty motherboard or other hardware.

Comment: But as i mentioned when i took it to a frinds house and tried, everything was working perfect.

Comment: It's possible that less flaky power could make it more stable, but I would expect that if you left it running for longer it would also exhibit the same issues at your friends house.

Comment: Thanks,  I was thinking about rewiring the house!I'll check and write back.Still cant see why all the service people I approach keep telling me theres nothing wrong  with it!

Comment: I hope it works out!

Comment: You were right John!

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit late to the party, but I'd suggest making sure that the "ground" pin on the outlet is actually connected to something. PC's need a ground connection or they can sometimes have weird issues. Don't hurt yourself while testing this!

To see if your CPU could be overheating, use a program like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php). While watching the graph, run a CPU stressor such [this one](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2005/10/22/Max-CPU_3A00_-Another-one-for-your-developer-toolbox_2E002E002E00_.aspx). If you see the temperature on the graph climb, and then the CPU shuts off, it's likely your CPU is overheating. If so, you should try reapplying thermal paste and/or replacing your heatsink/fan.

Comment: Do you think it could be because the thermal paste has not been applied properly?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem happen with my home build, and I tested the RAM (Started it up with one stick out, one stick in and then again with the other stick) and found that one of my sticks went bad and was causing this error.

So, i'd try testing the RAM out and seeing how that goes before doing anything else. Better to rule something out than assume it's a specific thing, paying money for new parts and finding it was something else all together.

Comment: But Ive got a single RAM module!

Answer (score 1):

It turned out my motherboard was broke.Replaced it.Doing fine now

Comment: When you update a question and there was already an answer that mentioned the reason or answer (the accepted answer), you can just edit your original question and add the information you have.  I would edit your original question instead of adding another 'answer' to update readers.